# Where is OSTYPE_solaris defined

Tags: visual-studio-2010, porting

I am porting code from Solaris to Windows Visual Studios. To make the code compatible with both, I am using statements such as #if defined (Win32) and #ifdef(OSTYPE_solaris). I found where Win32 is defined, but I cannot find where OSTYPE_solaris is defined. I am thinking that I may not find the definition of it because I am looking for it on Visual Studios, and the header that defines OSTYPE_solaris is not available on Visual Studios. Am I correct in that assumption? If so, does anyone know where OSTYPE_solaris is defined? I googled it a bit, but I was not finding luck with this question. I am also having the same conundrum with OSTYPE_linux.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is they are defined by compiler itself. If Solaris is using gcc as compiler, you could check compiler defined variables like this:

echo "" | gcc -E -dM -

But i think you should not ifdef by platform in most cases, it is better to use feature based defines like HAVE_SOCKET_H. But that requires much more work on multiplatform build system providing these defines and you may not need them.

Comment: I will look into other alternatives other than #ifdef. I am working on adding Visual Studios functionality to an already multi platform project, and #ifdef has been the convention for all other platforms, so changing it may not be an option now. 

I work much more on Visual Studios, so once I am in the Unix compiler I will try to use your advice to check out the OSTYPE!